# I can't open file using java with the help of file chooser dialog window on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code which I used on Windows OS.

```
        String fileToUpload = "\"C:\\development\\projects\\GMailTAbleTest\\1.xlsx\"";
    WebElement uploadButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[16]/div[2]"));
    uploadButton.click(); // This code find and click on button which open file chooser dialog window

StringSelection somestring = new StringSelection(fileToUpload);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(somestring, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(3000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

On Mac OS I tried to use VK_META (to simulate a command button) instead of VK_CONTROL.
I  am using the corresponding UNIX path:

```
String s ="\"/Users/Yevhenii/Documents/workspace/TableTEstGmail/1.xlsx\"";
```

Please help me, I have used a Mac for only a few weeks. I have tried to find the solution on the internet before wrote my question here. But I found no solution.

Comment: Well, where does it fail? Do you get any error messages? Does it do anything at all? Did you try to use a debugger and see how far it gets before it fails?

Comment: [link](http://youtu.be/f4AZdKUPzTM) here is a video record of my screen.
the fail starts when i try simulate COMMAND+V, to paste path to file. 
Maybe you know another way, how to open file via file chooser window.

Comment: Ah. You're trying to paste a string into the file opening dialog. Only problem is, MacOS X doesn't allow the user to enter a file path to a file opening dialog. Hence there is no field where you can paste text.

Comment: I tried simulate command+F and then paste the string with path to file, and its doesn't work too=(((
Do you know the way how to open file ??

Comment: It's not a good task for a robot. Why are you trying to open Google Drive through a browser rather than using their API?

Comment: i don't tried to use their API because the reason is to create automation test using selenium webDriver.
But for my opinion its a good way to use Google API but not in my case ((

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a following: mac os have another principle of opening files from open dialog instead of windows.
And as for me the easiest way to solve the problem is using robot.
So, when we click on our web page button which open, open dialog, we need select them. And we use for this key combination COMMAND + TAB. Realization code are following:

```
String filePath = "/Users/Yevhenii/Documents/workspace/TableTEstGmail/2.xlsx";
StringSelection somestring = new StringSelection(filePath);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(somestring, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(3000);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(90);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

Then we need to find our file by path. So when we press SHIFT + COMMAND + G it will opened window with the help of which we can open file by path. Realization code:

```
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

The next step is to paste path to our file and it will have following representation:

```
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);   
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Why we press ENTER(RETURN) two times ? First press accept inputed path and second press accepted selected file)

I really kill many time for solving this problem, maybe the reason, i new on mac os.
I hope this information will be interesting and important for you. ))

Regards Yevhenii

Comment: The solution is to wait in-between each press.